# Get Facebook ads 'Precise Interests' and 'Broad Categories' listing with 'Audience size' using PHP

Tags: php, facebook, ads

I want to get Facebook ads 'Precise Interests' and  'Broad Categories' listing with 'Audience size'. I read [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/topic-targeting/) and [that](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/targeting-specs/#likes_and_interests) Facebook API pages and directly tried it but it requires extended permissions and `access_token`.

Can I get list of 'Precise Interests' and  'Broad Categories' listing with 'Audience size' without `access_token`?

If no, what is best way to get these values without users extended permissions?

Thanks.